# How to create a string outside of Erlang that represents a DICT Term?

Tags: erlang

I want to construct a string in Java that represents a **DICT** term and that will  be passed to an Erlang process for being reflected back as an erlang term ( string-to-term ).

I can achieve this easily for ORDDICT 's, since they are structured as a simple sorted key / value pair in a list of tuples such as : [ {field1 , "value1"} , {field2 , "value2} ]

But, for DICTS, they are compiled into a specific term that I want to find how to reverse-engineer it. I am aware this structure can change over new releases, but the benefits for performance and ease of integration to Java would overcome this. Unfortunately Erlang's JInterface is based on simple data structures. An efficient DICT type would be of great use.

A simple dict gets defined as follows:

```
D1 = dict:store("field1","AAA",dict:new()).
{dict,1,16,16,8,80,48,
  {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},
  {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
    [["field1",65,65,65]],
    [],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}}
```

As it can be seen above, there are some coordinates which I do not understand what they mean ( the numbers 1,16,16,8,80,48 and a set of empty lists, which likely represent something as well.

Adding two other rows (key-value pairs) causes the data to look like:

```
D3 = dict:store("field3","CCC",D2).
{dict,3,16,16,8,80,48,
  {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},
  {{[],[],
    [["field3",67,67,67]],
    [],[],[],[],[],
    [["field1",65,65,65]],
    [],[],[],[],
    [["field2",66,66,66]],
    [],[]}}}
```

From the above I can notice that:

- the first number (3) reppresets the number of items in the DICT.
- the second number (16) shows the number of list **slots** in the first tuple of lists
- the third number (16) shows the number of list **slots** in the second typle of lists, of which the values ended up being placed on ( in the middle ).
- the fourth number (8) appears to be the number of slots in the second row of tuples from where the values are placed ( a sort of index-pointer )
- the remaining numbers (80 and 48)... no idea...
- adding a key "field0" gets placed not in the end but just after "field1"'s data. This indicates the indexing approach.

**So the question**, is there a way (algorithm) to reliably directly create a DICT string from outside of Erlang ?

Comment: Generally speaking, it's not good practice to depend on the internal workings of a library rather than the public interface.  The internals may change at any time, while the interface should remain stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comprehensive specification how dict is implemented can be found simply in the [dict.erl](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/dict.erl) sourcecode.

But I'm not sure replicating dict.erl's implementation in Java is worthwhile.  This would only make sense if you want a fast dict like data structure that you need to pass often between Java and Erlang code.  It might make more sense to use a Key-Value store both from Erlang and Java without passing it directly around.  Depending on your application this could be e.g. [riak](http://basho.com/riak/) or maybe even connect your different language worlds with [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com).  Both examples are implemented in Erlang and are easily accessible from both worlds.

Comment: thanks. I am actually already using RabbitMq for communication purposes, but wanted to send a pre-digested DICT to an erlang queue consumer for performance reasons ( cost of producing a proplist on the java side versus creating a DICT directly rather than rewinding it on the erlang side. Only benchmarks can tell... I will play with the dict.erl sourcecode as you suggest. 600+ lines of code ... does not appear too challenging and might be worth forwarding this to the JInterface line of code.

Comment: @gextra you will need a Java implementation of `erlang:phash/2` if you want to go down that route. https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/cbd1378ee1fde835e55614bac9290b281bafe49a/erts/emulator/beam/utils.c#L894